# DebugIds in GWT application hosted mode

Tags: java, debugging, gwt

How do I get debug ids to display in hosted mode in my gwt application?

I am already implementing onEnsureDebugId and am calling ensureDebugId on my entry point, but they're not displaying :(

Comment: Have you added <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/> to your *.gwt.xml ?

Comment: What do you mean by _displaying_?

Comment: Added the com.google.gwt.user.Debug and it worked :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added  to my *.gwt.xml and it worked